# Another proof of $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}|\cos{n}|=1$

Tags: calculus, limits, limsup-and-liminf, diophantine-approximation

I have seen a [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3729557/some-question-about-proving-displaystyle-limsup-n-to-infty-cosn-1-by-usin) of $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}|\cos{n}|=1$ by using density of $\{a+b\alpha: a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ in  $R$, where $\alpha$ is irrational.

Here I give another proof of  as following:

See this [article](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183502433), a special case is that there is two increasing sequences of odd positive integers $(p_n),(q_n)$ such that
$$ \left|\pi - \frac{p_n}{q_n} \right| \leq  \frac{1}{q_n^2},\quad n>1.$$

Note that $|\cos (\pi-x) |= |\cos x |$ for $x\in [0,\pi]$, then
$$|\cos \left(q_n\pi - p_n\right)|=  |\cos p_n| \geq \cos\frac{1}{q_n} \to 1.$$
therefore $|\cos p_n|\to 1$.

Is this solution right? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed alternate proof looks good, but for clarity, I would provide a little more detail:$\\[6pt]$
\begin{align*}
&
\left|\pi-\frac{p_n}{q_n} \right|\le \frac{1}{q_n^2}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\left|q_n\pi-p_n\right|\le\frac{1}{q_n}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
0 \le \left|q_n\pi-p_n\right|\le\frac{1}{q_n} < \pi\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\cos\left(\left|q_n\pi-p_n\right|\right)\ge\cos\Bigl(\frac{1}{q_n}\Bigr)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\cos\left(q_n\pi-p_n\right)\ge\cos\Bigl(\frac{1}{q_n}\Bigr)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\cos\left(\pi-p_n\right)\ge\cos\Bigl(\frac{1}{q_n}\Bigr)
&&\text{[since $q_n$ is odd]}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
-\cos(p_n)\ge\cos\Bigl(\frac{1}{q_n}\Bigr)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\cos(p_n)\le -\cos\Bigl(\frac{1}{q_n}\Bigr)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos(p_n)=-1
&&\text{[since the sequence $(q_n)$ is increasing]}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\lim_{n\to\infty} |\cos(p_n)|=1
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the detail.