# To show the set is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For every irrational $\alpha$, the set $\{a+b\alpha: a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136665)

I want to show that

> Given any irrational number $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$, the set $\displaystyle S=\{ m+n\alpha : m,n\in Z \}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

[Kronecker's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html) gives us that the set $\{ma\}_{m \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is dense in $(0,1)$ for irrational $a$, and hence, that the set $\{n+ma\}_{m,n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

If you want to prove Kronecker's Theorem, you may use [Weyl's Criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_criterion), which proves more  strongly, that the said sequence is equidistributed too!

Comment: Please write the statement of Kronecker's theorem!

Comment: I've edited to give the link of Kronecker's Theorem. Hope this helps.

Comment: With $a=\pi$, I don't find a *single* integer $m$ so that $0<ma<1$. That's quite the opposite of "dense in $(0,1)$".

Comment: @celtschk The notation $\{ma\}$ is the decimal part of $ma$.

Comment: It may be noted that Kronecker's Theorem has a rather simple proof using the Pigeonhole Principle. See the answer to the question which is a duplicate of this.

Comment: OK, maybe when using $\{\}$ in any other way than to denote sets, it would be a good idea to explicitly say that :-) Especially since your second use obviously *is* using it just to denote a set (the set of fractional parts of $n+ma$ definitely is *not* dense in $\mathbb{R}$).