# fractional parts of $n\alpha$ for irrational $\alpha$ and connected problems

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

$\{$ fractional part of $n\alpha\mid n \in \mathbb{N}$ $\}$ is a dense subset of $[0,1]$ for an irrational number $\alpha$. 
- this is a known theorem.

Wouldn't it be true with $\mathbb{N}$ replaced with the set of primes?

For the set of powers of 2 it doesn't hold, I found an interesting topic:
[The density --- or otherwise --- of $\{\{2^N\,\alpha\}:N\in\mathbb{N}\}$ for ALL irrational $\alpha$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342747/the-density-or-otherwise-of-2n-alpha-n-in-mathbbn-for-all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is YES. A stronger result is known that $2\alpha, 3\alpha, 5\alpha, \ldots \pmod 1$ is equidistributed on $[0,1)$.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Equidistribution_modulo_1

Comment: Thanks, but this is a respectable theorem, the density is only an easy corollary from it. So now I ask if it's possible to give an elementary proof of density without using Vinogradov's theorem.