# Is the LLL algorithm only applicable with integers?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Why cannot it apply with a basis defined with irrational numbers? For example, such a basis:

$(1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) $, $(1, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7 })$ and $(1, \sqrt{11}, \sqrt{13 })$.

Answer (score 2):

It can be applied to any basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$, including your example.
The original paper of the LLL-algorithm ([Factoring Polynomials with Rational Coefficients](https://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/scans/lll.pdf)) defines the algorithm on any lattice, and defines lattice as $L := \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n r_i b_i \;|\; r_i \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$, where $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n$ is any basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$. 
Most of the applications indeed use vectors in $\mathbb{Z}^n$, but not all, for example the article [On multidimensional Diophantine approximation of algebraic numbers](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Michael_Pohst/publication/307999060_On_multidimensional_Diophantine_approximation_of_algebraic_numbers/links/57fb653308ae280dd0c4b284.pdf) uses the LLL-algorithm for vectors with algebraic number coordinates (e.g. $\sqrt{2}$ is an algebraic number, but $\pi$ is not).

Answer (score 0):

The input and the output of the LLL algorithm is a basis for a lattice, not a basis for a vector space. The span of your vectors isn't a lattice, and so it doesn't fit the conceptual scheme of the algorithm.

Note that in some restricted cases you can have irrationals. For example $(1,2\pi),(2,\pi)$ form a lattice and so the algorithm can be used with those two inputs.

**Edit:** Here's an argument that might convince you that your set doesn't form a lattice. Instead of your example, we'll look at $(1,1),(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. The set of $\mathbb{Z}$ combinations takes the form $\{(a+b\sqrt{2},a+b\sqrt{3}):a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

By the theorem in the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272545/multiples-of-an-irrational-number-forming-a-dense-subset), the numbers of the form $a+br$ are dense in $(0,1)$ for every irrational $r$, and by increasing $a$ we can translate the set and see that it's dense in $\mathbb{R}$. This tells us that we can find a set of values for $a$ and $b$ such that the first coordinate is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and that we can do it separately for the second. However, the defining property of a lattice is that it's discrete, and so the set generated by these two vectors doesn't form a lattice.

Now, your set doesn't have a vector of all ones, but we can fix that. If you take one dimension and scale all the vectors by a constant factor, you preserve the fact that it's a lattice. So when you have $(1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}),(1,\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7})$ we can scale the second coordinate by $\sqrt{2}$ and the third by $\sqrt{3}$ to get $(1,1,1),(1,\sqrt{5/2},\sqrt{7/3})$. By the same argument, linear combinations of these two vectors don't form a lattice, and so the original vectors cannot! Adding in the third vector doesn't make things better, because adding in additional vectors can only increase the number of points we can reach

Comment: Frankly speaking, I do not understand. Of course you can use integral coefficients before the three vectors above to form a lattice. What do you mean by saying the span of my vectors is not a lattice?

Comment: @S.Kohn $\{x=av_1+bv_2+cv_3:a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is not discrete for your $v_1,v_2,v_3$. Although the first coordinates can only be integers, the second and third take on a set of values that are dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @S.Kohn You can use the theorem proved here to prove that your set isn't discrete: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272545/multiples-of-an-irrational-number-forming-a-dense-subset

Comment: But that problem takes only the fractional part of the number. For any irrational number $q$, the numbers $\{ n q , n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ indeed forms a lattice.

Comment: @S.Kohn my response is long, so I edited it into my answer.

Comment: Sorry, 'we can do it separately for the second'? The second component is not independent of the first. Do not do algebra. Just use geometry. Picture it in your mind. Apparently (1,1) and $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ can form a lattice.

Comment: @S.Kohn I meant that you can make the first or the second coordinate dense with a set of values for $a$ and $b$ separately but not necessarily simultaneously.

Comment: source for them forming a lattice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55251/discussion-between-s-kohn-and-stella-biderman).