# Hard Problem on Limit Points.

Tags: real-analysis

Find the set of all limit points of the sequence $a_{n}=n\alpha-\lceil n\alpha \rceil,\alpha\not \in \mathbb{Q}.$

This problem is particularly easy when $a\in \mathbb{Q}$, but somehow the same techniques fail to work when $\alpha$ is irrational. Any help/hint on this problem will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is that the floor or ceiling function?

Comment: In my book it means the least integer greater than or equal to $n\alpha.$

Comment: I am not sure what the terms floor or ceiling mean....

Comment: Then it's ceiling. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Comment: When $\alpha$ is irrational, the set $\{n\alpha - \lceil n\alpha \rceil : n\in\mathbb{N} \}$ will be dense in the interval $[-1,0]$.  Thus the set of all limit points is that interval.  [This is related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272545/multiples-of-an-irrational-number-forming-a-dense-subset)