# Is $n!\alpha \bmod 1$ dense in $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, factorial

We know that positive integer times a irrational number modulo $1$ generate a dense set in $[0,1]$. According the answer of this post:[Multiples of an irrational number forming a dense subset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272545/multiples-of-an-irrational-number-forming-a-dense-subset). I see no reason why the proof cannot be extended to $n!\alpha$ for $\alpha$ be an irrational number. We can just replace $i$ and $j$ with $i!$ and $j!$ and the argument still holds. Is that true?

Comment: Can you clarify if $\alpha$ or $n$ is fixed or both are allowed to vary?

Comment: Use `\bmod` to get proper spacing for the binary operation.

Comment: Neither $n!e$ nor $n!/e$ are dense modulo $1.$ Use that $e=\sum_{k=0 }^{\infty} \frac 1{k!}$ for the first and $e^{-1}= \sum_{k=0 }^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^k}{k!}$ for the second.

Comment: You can't just adapt the other proof, because you don't know if $k(i! - j!)$ will be a factorial.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen: your comment is the most important here. While studying a proof one must try to grasp where and how each hypotheses is related to some part of a proof.

Answer (score 12):

I presume you mean $n!\alpha$ (not $n!/\alpha$).

Try $\alpha=e$. (Yes, that $e$.)
Then
$$n!e=\text{integer}+\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}+\cdots$$
so modulo $1$, $n!e$ is between $1/(n+1)$ and $1/n$, so the $n!e$ are certainly not dense modulo $1$
in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Of course, $n!/e$ works similarly.

Comment: Great answer! I like it!

Comment: And the same is true of all numbers of the form $x = \sum_k c_k/n!$ where $\{c_k\}$ is a bounded set of nonnegative integers.  And the cardinality of these is
the continuum.  So even if you didn't know $e$ is transcendental, uncountably many of these are transcendental.