# Example of a function that is strictly increasing on a dense set, but not monotone on any subinterval

Tags: continuity, monotone-functions

I search for an example of a function defined on $[0,1]$, **strictly increasing** on $A=\{\{n\sqrt{2}\}|~n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, which is **not monotone** on any interval $I\subset [0,1]$

Maybe there is a simple example, but I cannot see it yet...

By a density result (of the set $A$ in $[0,1]$) it follows that such a function cannot be continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Here's a really dumb example that answers both your titular question and your question in the body (which shouldn't be different, so you should change one of them): $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1-x&x\in\mathbb Q\\x&x\notin\mathbb Q\end{cases}$$

Comment: Why is continuity a bad thing? And $A$ is not dense...

Comment: For any irrational $a$ the set $\{\{na\}\}$ is dense in $[0,1)$.

Comment: That is false. As a counterexample, note that for any irrational $a$, $|a|>0$, so let $\varepsilon=\frac{|a|}5$. Thus a ball of radius $\varepsilon$ around each element of $\{\{na\}\}$ doesn't contain any other element.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272545/multiples-of-an-irrational-number-forming-a-dense-subset

Comment: Ah, you mean the fractional component. I see.