# Problem suggested by the Pythagorean musica scale

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is the set of fractions $3^m/2^n$ dense in the interval [1,2]?
If this can help: for each m there is exactly one n in the interval ($n$=integer part of $m\gamma$ , where $\gamma=\log 3/\log 2$)

Comment: I edited your formatting, I hope for clarity... Don't forget the "dollar signs" if you're wishing to use TeX.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the set of such fractions is dense in $[1, 2]$. The proof below is an elaboration of Henning Makholm's answer.

1. The fractions $\dfrac{3^m}{2^n}$ being dense in $[1, 2]$ is equivalent to the *logarithms* of those fractions being dense in $[\log 1, \log 2]$.
   **Proof**: This is because the inverse of the logarithm function is continuous: a neighbourhood of $x \in [1, 2]$ contains the image of a neighbourhood of $\log x \in [\log 1, \log 2]$.
   In concrete terms, if you want to show that for a particular $x$, for every $\epsilon$ there exists $(m, n)$ such that $|x - 3^m/2^n| < \epsilon$, it's enough to show that for every $\delta$ there exists $(m, n)$ such that $|\log x - \log(3^m/2^n)| < \delta$, as for sufficiently small $\delta$ (possibly depending on $x$ and $\epsilon$), we have $|\log x - \log(3^m/2^n)| < \delta \implies |x - 3^m/2^n| < \epsilon$.
2. The logarithm of $\dfrac{3^m}{2^n}$ is $m\log 3 - n\log 2$. We want to prove that the set of such numbers is dense $[0, \log 2]$, or, equivalently, dividing throughout by $\log 2$ (which again we can do because this operation has a continuous inverse, say), we want to prove that the set of numbers of the form $m\frac{\log 3}{\log 2} - n$ is dense in $[0, 1]$.
   As you observed, for any integer $m$, there is a unique integer $n = \left\lfloor \frac{m\log 3}{\log 2} \right\rfloor$ such that $m \log 3 - n\log 2$ lies in $[0, \log 2]$, or equivalently, such that $m \frac{\log 3}{\log 2} - n$ lies in $[0, 1]$). So $m \frac{\log 3}{\log 2} - n$ is precisely the fractional part of $m\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}$. The question now is to prove that the fractional parts of $m\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}$ are dense in $[0, 1]$.
3. There is a well-known result that if $\alpha$ is irrational, then the set of fractional parts of $m\alpha$ as $m$ ranges over the natural numbers, is dense in $[0, 1]$. This you can see proved on this site, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272545/multiples-of-an-irrational-number-forming-a-dense-subset), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136665/how-to-show-this-is-a-dense-set), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189397/why-is-this-quotient-space-not-hausdorff/189402#189402) and even on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pigeonhole_principle&oldid=548900480#Uses_and_applications). Basically, you can use the pigeonhole principle: if you want to show that the fractional part of some $m\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}$ is within some distance $\frac{1}{q}$ of some number, consider more than $q$ such numbers; two of the fractional parts lie in the same $\frac{1}{q}$ "bucket"; by considering their difference and a suitable multiple, you can put the fractional part into the bucket you want.
4. The number $\dfrac{\log 3}{\log 2}$ is irrational, because of $\dfrac{\log 3}{\log 2} = \dfrac{p}{q}$, then it means that $3^q = 2^p$, which is impossible for nonzero $q$. This concludes the proof.

Comment: Thanks for picking this up.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Thanks a lot for your note and information. This settles my question. Not being this my domain, I was not aware of this well-known result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The set of multiples of $\log 3$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ modulo $\log 2$, because $\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}$ is irrational. If it was rational there'd be a nontrivial power of 2 that was also a power of 3, which contradicts the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: It's probably not obvious to the OP why multiples of $\log 3$ being dense in $\mathbb{R}$ modulo $\log 2$ is equivalent to the set of fractions $3^m / 2^n$ being dense in $[1, 2]$; a line or two showing this would help.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: SInce the OP himself makes the connection to the integer parts of $m\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}$, I don't think he will have a problem with moving to a logarithmic representation of the problem.

Comment: If I understand correctly the rather cryptical note of Makholm, he just reformulated the problem, without solving it. I will reformulate it by taking logarithms and dividing by log 2. Let $\phi(m)$=integer part of $m\gamma$ (where $\gamma=log 3/log 2$).Problem*: Is the set of reals of the form $r_m=m\gamma-\phi(m)$ dense in the interval [0,1]? Gonzalo

Comment: @Gonzalo: The answer is yes, because $\gamma$ is irrational, *and* there is a well-known result that if a number $\gamma$ is irrational, the fractional parts of its multiples (which is your numbers $r_m$) is dense in $[0, 1]$. See my answer for an elaboration.