# Showing that the sum of these two closed subsets is a countable dense subset.

Tags: real-analysis

I am having a really difficult time proving part two of this problem in Baby Rudin.

> If$\,\,A\subset\mathbb{R^k}$ and $B\subset\mathbb{R^k}$, define $A+B$ to be the set of all sums $x+y$ with $x\in A$ and $y\in B$.
>
> (b) Let $\alpha$ be an irrational real number. Let $C_1$ be the set of all integers, let $C_2$ be the set of all $n\alpha$ with $n\in C_1$. Show that $C_1$ and $C_2$ are closed subsets of $\mathbb{R^1}$ whose sum $C_1+C_2$ is not closed, by showing that $C_1+C_2$ is a countable dense subset.

I understand that both $C_1$ and $C_2$ are closed, and I understand why $C_1+C_2$ might be dense, but I am just having no luck figuring out how to tackle the problem.

Here are two possible ideas I think might work, but don't know how to make work:

1. Prove that for every element $z\notin C_1+C_2$ and every $\epsilon$, there exist an element $c\in C_1+C_2$ such that $|z-c|<\epsilon$.
2. Assuming $z\notin C_1+C_2$, prove that if  $ d_z:\mathbb{R^1}\to \mathbb{R^1}$ where $d_z(x)=|z-x|,$ then $\inf (f(C_1+C_2))=0$

Any ideas as to what might be the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Neatly presented! :)

Comment: Asked and answered: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136665/for-every-irrational-alpha-the-set-ab-alpha-a-b-in-mathbbz-is-den

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For every irrational $\alpha$, the set $\{a+b\alpha: a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136665/for-every-irrational-alpha-the-set-ab-alpha-a-b-in-mathbbz-is-den)

Answer (score 0):

Hint regarding your first idea: you only need one such $z, c$ pair for each $\varepsilon$.