# About density of $\{\alpha n+m:(n,m)\in \mathbb{Z}^2\}$

Tags: real-analysis

We know that if $\alpha$ is irrational then set $\{\alpha n+m:(n,m)\in \mathbb{Z}^2\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^1$.

Let's take a look at set $\{2\sqrt{2\pi n}+2\pi m+1: (n,m)\in \mathbb{Z^2}\}$. Is this set is dense in $\mathbb{R^1}$? If answer yes then can we prove it's density from density of $\{\alpha n+m:(n,m)\in \mathbb{Z}^2\}$?

Comment: $\sqrt{2\pi n}$ is not defined for $n<0$.

Comment: @JohnMa, I have more general question: Is $\{\alpha n+\beta m: (n,m)\in \mathbb{Z}^2\}$ dense in reals? where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are irrational

Comment: It depends on whether $\alpha/\beta$ is rational.

Comment: @RaheemNajib Yes, iff $\alpha/\beta$ is irrational (this is just a scaled version of $\{\alpha n+m\}$)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro, Where I can find proof of this fact? Can you show the proof?

Comment: @RaheemNajib http://math.stackexchange.com/a/136685/50776 gives the proof for $\{\alpha n+m\}$, but you say you already know this fact. From that, it is simply a special case that if $A$ is dense then so is $rA$ for any positive real $r$, since any element $x\in A$ which is $\epsilon/r$-close to $y/r$ yields $rx\in rA$ which is $\epsilon$-close to $y$.

Answer (score 3):

It is dense in $\Bbb R$, but for a much simpler reason: $2\sqrt {2\pi (n+1)}-2\sqrt {2\pi n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, while $2\sqrt {2\pi n}\to\infty$. Thus for any $\epsilon$ we eventually have $\epsilon$-close points above some $N$ (and in particular covering an interval $[N,N+2\pi]$ of length $2\pi$), and we can shift this to an interval covering any chosen point using the $2\pi m+1$ term.

Comment: Dear Mario! It's reaaly nice fact that if $a_{n+1}-a_{n}\to 0$ and $a_n\to \infty$ then $\{a_n\}$ is dense in real numbers. Right? Is proof of this is hard?

Comment: @RaheemNajib I've sketched the argument right here, but I'm afraid I don't know a good reference. You also need to assume that $a_n$ is monotonically increasing, and it is not $\{a_n\}$ but $\{a_n+m:n\in\Bbb N,m\in\Bbb Z\}$ that is dense. (The $2\pi$ and $+1$ factors can be easily removed by rescaling and shifting the set.)

Comment: Dear Mario! Your statement seems really interesting and useful to me and I proved it here - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528812/structure-of-dense-subset-of-mathbbr. Can you look at my proof?