# Structure of dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1528360/274227) user Mario Carneiro formulated statement which I find really interesting and useful and I proved it and I would like to know is my proof correct?

> If sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ implies the following conditions:
>
> 1) $a_1<a_2<\dots<a_{n}<\dots$
>
> 2) $a_n\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$
>
> 3) $a_{n+1}-a_{n}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$
>
> Then $\{a_n+m: (n,m)\in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^1$.

**Proof:** Taking $x\in \mathbb{R}^1$ and let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then $\exists k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_k<x<a_{k+1}$ (assuming that $x>a_1$). Then $\exists N:=N_{\epsilon}$ such that $n\geqslant N$ implies $a_{n+1}-a_n<\epsilon$.

1) If $k\geqslant N$ then $|x-a_k|<\epsilon.$

2) If $k<N$ then $\exists M\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x+M\in(a_l, a_{l+1})$ where $l\geqslant N$ then $|x+M-a_l|<\epsilon.$

If $x\leqslant a_1$ then $\exists K\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x+K>a_1$ and we can apply previous reasoning for $x+K$.
Q.E.D.

**Remark:** If $A$ is dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^1$ then: 1) for any $r>0$ the set $rA$ also dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$. 2) for any $c\in \mathbb{R}$ the set $c+A$ also dense.

Comment: Maybe you meant "satisfies" instead of "implies".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are just two very small corrections that need to be made. First, there is a $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $a_k\color{red}{\le}x<a_{k+1}$. And secondly, in $(2)$ there is an $M\in\Bbb N$ such that $x+M\in\color{red}[a_\ell,a_{\ell+1})$ for some $\ell\ge N$.

Comment: Everything else is in OK?

Comment: @RFZ: It would be better English to say ‘If the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ **satisfies** the following conditions’, but I didn’t see any other problems with the mathematics.

Comment: Yes you're right. I am trying to make my English better :) Thank you very much for your attention! +1

Comment: @RFZ: You’re welcome! (And your English is already quite good.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your permanent help! Nice to hear it from you :)

Comment: Dear Brian! Sorry that bother you but day ago I proved that problem from Rudin which was really hard to me since I thought on it more that two days. Can you check my solution please? I would be really greatful.

Comment: @RFZ: Do you mean [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532517/integration-by-parts-in-riemann-stieltjes-integral-from-rudin)? I’m going to bed now, but I’ll take a look tomorrow. (I warn you, though, it’s been 30 years since I last looked at Riemann-Stieltjes integrals, so I may be a bit slow!)

Comment: Thanks a lot, dear Brian! It would be great! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the original proof I had in mind differs a little, I'll write it down here. (Also it turns out that the monotonicity assumption $a_1\le a_2\le\dots$ is not necessary.)

Take $\epsilon>0$. By assumption (2), there is some $N$ such that $a_{n+1}-a_n\le\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$.

*Lemma:* The sequence $a_n$ is $\epsilon$-dense in $[a_N,\infty)$. *Proof:* Take $x\ge a_N$ and let $k\ge N$ be the least integer such that $a_k\ge x$. Existence is guaranteed by assumption (3). Then $a_k-\epsilon\le a_{k-1}<x$ since $a_{k+1}-a_k\le\epsilon$ and $\lnot(a_{k-1}\ge x)$, so $a_k\in[x,x+\epsilon)$ and thus $a_k$ is $\epsilon$-close to $x$.

Returning to the main theorem, given $x\in\Bbb R$ we can find an $m\in\Bbb Z$ such that $x-a_N-m\in[0,1)$ (explicitly, $m=\lfloor x-a_n\rfloor$). Then by the lemma there is an $a_k$ which is $\epsilon$-close to $x-m$, and so $a_k+m$ is $\epsilon$-close to $x$. Thus $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty+\Bbb Z$ is $\epsilon$-dense in $\Bbb R$ for all $\epsilon$, which is equivalent to it being dense in $\Bbb R$.