# The Set of integer multiples of two irrational numbers is dense in reals?

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, elementary-number-theory

Let $\alpha , \beta $ be the linearly independent irrational numbers over $\mathbb Q$ with $\alpha > \beta > 0 $ , and $\mathrm A=\{n\alpha-m\beta \mid  n,m  \text{ are nonnegative integers}  \}$

How to prove that $\mathrm A$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ ? Is it true?

Comment: This has been asked sooo often. For example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136665/for-every-irrational-alpha-the-set-ab-alpha-a-b-in-mathbbz-is-den

Comment: @amsmath The only obstacle I see is that the OP wants $m,n\in\Bbb N$, not $\in\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score -1):

Note that

- $A$ is closed under addition
- $\inf A=-\infty$
- $\sup \{\,x\in A\mid x>0\,\}=0$.

The first is trivial, the second follows from $\beta>0$, and only the third involves the $\Bbb Q$-linear independence of $\alpha,\beta$.

Comment: The third does not make sense

Comment: The third is wrong..

Comment: Do you mean $x < 0$?

Comment: I'm not sure why you rejected my edit to the third bullet point: it makes no sense as written.