# Take $f$ and entire function such that $f(z) = f(z+1)=f(z+\sqrt{2})$, then it is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, periodic-functions, entire-functions

I am working through some practice problems and I have this one which is stumping me:

Take $f$ and entire function such that $f(z) = f(z+1)=f(z+\sqrt{2})$, then it is constant.

I was thinking, given the function is entire, then it has a Taylor series expansion about the origin, with an infinite radius of convergence:

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}(z+1)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}(z+\sqrt{2})^n$$

Which we can also write:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}z^k = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}z^k\sqrt{2}^{n-k}$$

But I am not quite sure this is the correct place to go. Any ideas as to how I can move forward on this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos so the value that is added does not matter?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Note however that $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are linearly dependent, so something else needs to be done.

Comment: I made a mistake. It is *not* a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: Yes, I also find the level of the answers on the other question to be quite high. Could I get some hint on the thought process for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the set $D$ of the numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt2$, with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ form a dense subset of $\mathbb R$. Since $f$ is continuous and constant on $D$, $f|_{\mathbb R}$ is constant. It follows from the identity theorem that $f$ is constant.

Comment: I understand the use of the identity theorem assuming D is dense, However, do you mind further elaborating why D is dense? I am not quite familiar with the concept. In fact, when I learned the Identity theorem I learned it in the context of an accumulation point

Comment: For every real numbers $x$ and $y$, with $x<y$, there is a number of the frm $a+b\sqrt2$ (with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$) such that $x<a+b\sqrt2<y$. In other words, the numbers of that form are spread everywhere (in $\mathbb R$). It follows from this that every continuous function from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$ whch is constant on $D$ is actually constant everywhere.

Comment: That is interesting, is there a theorem or a property that I could look into in order to prove the claim that $a+b\sqrt{2}$ can be made to be between any two real numbers, taking $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: You will find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136665/for-every-irrational-alpha-the-set-ab-alpha-a-b-in-mathbbz-is-den?noredirect=1&lq=1).