# Meromorphic function satisfying $f(z) = f(z+1) =f(z + \sqrt{2}$) is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was looking this question and answer [Take $f$ and entire function such that $f(z) = f(z+1)=f(z+\sqrt{2})$, then it is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2984535/take-f-and-entire-function-such-that-fz-fz1-fz-sqrt2-then-it-is) and I wonder what would happen if $f$ is not entire but meromorphic.

Thank you.

Comment: Pole is a very nice type of singularity, allowing you to conclude the same answer as in the link.

Comment: How could I do it? I thought it was enough to say that poles must be isolated and there must be a finite number of them, so taking a neighbourhood of $\sqrt(2)$ it would be right. However, I did not know either if it was okay or how to formalise it.

Comment: Your argument is just fine. Since the set of all poles of a meromorphic function is discrete, the complement is connected and open. So you can apply the identity theorem to conclude.

Comment: The same logic José Carlos Santos uses in the other thread shows that if $p$ is a pole, then poles must be dense on the line $p + \Bbb R$.

Comment: If you are discussing meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$, by definition, the set of poles must be discrete. This restriction is essential because people want to regard meromorphic functions as holomorphic functions as holomorphic function to the Riemann sphere $\hat{\mathbb{C}} = P^1\mathbb{C}$. But if you are willing to restrict the domain of $f$ to a smaller region $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{C}$, then we can make poles 'accumulate' towards the boundary of $\Omega$.

Comment: Still, the conclusion will continue to hold for any domain $\Omega$ which is connected and is invariant under shifts by $m+n\sqrt{2}$ for $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and this can be proved by almost the same argument as in the link.