# Does there always exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $0 < \sin \sqrt{n} < \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For this problem, my approach was to prove that $\sqrt{n}\mod 1$ is dense in $(0,1)$ and then extend the results to say $\sqrt{n}\mod\pi$ is dense in $(0,\pi)$. Once that is proved then the result follows immediately. However I'm not sure how to prove the first part.

By $\sqrt{n} \mod 1$, I mean the fractional part of $\sqrt{n}$ or $\sqrt{n} - \lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor$

By $\sqrt{n} \mod \pi$, I mean $\sqrt{n} - \pi\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\pi}\rfloor$

Comment: Does this help you? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3423465/everywhere-dense-set-sqrtn-mod-1

Comment: Ah yes that's it! Is it straightforward to extend to the second part?

Comment: this should be enough https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4764/862429