# How to prove that there exist $n\in N$,such that $\{nb\}>\frac{1}{a}$

Tags: number-theory

Let $a>1$, and $b$ be irrational numbers, show that: There exist $n\in N^{+}$, such that
$$\{nb\}>\dfrac{1}{a}$$
where $\{x\}=x-[x]$

My idea: since
$$\{nb\}=nb-[nb]$$

we only prove
$$nb-[nb]>\dfrac{1}{a}$$
then
$$nb-\dfrac{1}{a}>[nb]$$
then I can't, thank you very much

Comment: see this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19565/proving-that-the-terms-of-the-sequence-nx-nx-is-dense-in-0-1

Comment: Hello,Then? Thank you

Comment: Once you have $\{\{nb\}:n\in \mathbb {Z}\}$ is dense in $(0,1)$, it means for any $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, you get $\{n'b\} > \epsilon$ for some $n' \in \mathbb{Z}$